# Powershell script cannot delete a directory

Tags: powershell, locking

I have written a powershell script to uninstall a service and then delete the folder in which the service is installed.
The script uninstalls the service without any issues but it cannot delete the directory...it says that the directory is in use. When I try to delete the directory manually it removes just fine....I've tried all sorts of ways to get this done but nothing worked.The service is installed in $INSTALL_DIR\server

```
function env_check () 
{
Try
{   
    Start-Transcript -Path C:\Deployment_Script.txt.log -ErrorAction Stop

    if (Get-Service "ESL_SERVICE" -ErrorAction Continue)
    {

        $arrService = Get-Service -Name ESL_SERVICE
        if ($arrService.Status -eq 'Running')
        {
            Stop-Service ESL_SERVICE
        }

        cd $INSTALL_DIR\server
        sc.exe delete "ESL_Service" -ErrorAction Stop
    }
    Remove-Item "$INSTALL_DIR\server" -Force -Recurse
    Remove-Item "$INSTALL_DIR\client" -Force -Recurse
    Remove-Item "$INSTALL_DIR\DB Migration" -Force -Recurse
}
Catch
{
    Write-Output $_.Exception.Message
    New-Item -Path $LOG_PATH  -ItemType directory -ErrorAction Stop
    Copy-Item -Force C:\Deployment_Script.txt.log $LOG_PATH\. -ErrorAction Stop
    exit
}
}
```

Comment: verifiy the content of '$INSTALL_DIR' INTO your function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are blocking yourself by `cd $INSTALL_DIR\server`

As proof of concept you can try following

```
New-Item $env:temp\server -ItemType Directory
# by navigating to the folder we wish to delete we get an 'in use' error message
cd $env:temp\server
Remove-Item "$($env:temp)\server" -force -recurse
```

Explicitly navigating out of the folder allows deleting

```
New-Item $env:temp\server -ItemType Directory
cd $env:temp
Remove-Item "$($env:temp)\server" -force -recurse
```

Comment: Thank You very much